# How to select part of a text on mysql?

Tags: mysql, text, summarization

I have a column saved as `LONGTEXT` on mysql. This text saves rich text. I'm currently reading all the text then fixing it using javascript to get the first `100` characters in a way not to split the word in its middle.

Yet this way don't seem the best way to do it. I want to select a summary directly using the query, yet I also want to be careful not to include characters that are html tags.

The function below seems working fine to strip the html.

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
RETURNS varchar(4000)
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
  WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
    BEGIN
      SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
      SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
      IF iLength > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
          SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
        END;
      END IF;
    END;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN Dirty;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of solution is to select text stripped use

This is the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) function like php function strip_tags

```
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS htmlStrip;
CREATE FUNCTION htmlStrip(pmXml longtext)RETURNS longtext
DETERMINISTIC
htmlStrip:
BEGIN 
        DECLARE vStart INTEGER ;
    DECLARE vEnd INTEGER ;
    DECLARE vResult LONGTEXT;
    DECLARE vCount1 INTEGER;
    DECLARE vCount2 INTEGER;

    SET vResult:=pmXml;
    SET vCount1:=LENGTH(vResult)-LENGTH(REPLACE(vResult,'<',''));
    SET vCount2:=LENGTH(vResult)-LENGTH(REPLACE(vResult,'>',''));
    IF vCount1<>vCount2 THEN 
              RETURN 'Input Error'; 
    END IF;

    WHILE (LOCATE('<',vResult) OR LOCATE('>',vResult)) DO
         SET vStart:=LOCATE('<',vResult);
         SET vEnd:=LOCATE('>',vResult);
         SET vResult:=REPLACE(vResult,SUBSTRING(vResult,vStart,vEnd-vStart+1),'');
    END WHILE;
    RETURN vResult;
END;

    SELECT htmlStrip('<html>hello<body> how r u?</body></html>') AS Result

Result
--------
hello how r u?
```

so you need to use [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) + strip_tags

Comment: Are you sure from this function? I tried it and it took long time and it did not return result until now, as if it is entering in infinite loop.

Comment: i take this function from mysql site comments i link to this page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html, he run this function and get results, what the size of your field ?

Comment: you can look another strip tags function in web , i found another in http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280 or in http://www.discussweb.com/database-support/4575-how-strip-html-tags-mysql.html

Comment: i think the function in http://www.discussweb.com/database-support/4575-how-strip-html-tags-mysql.html is better, try it

Comment: I posted the working function
now on the query I'm doing the following:

` select SUBSTRING(fnStripTags(col),1,100) from table`

Yet I still have 2 problems, first is it related to case having new line, the sentence is getting merged together with not even a space, and the second is that the sentence may end with non complete words.